# How can I search internal blocks in the admin section?

Tags: search

I've inherited a very large site that I didn't build. I am trying to find one particular block amid around a hundred - I'd like to search these blocks for some of the specific HTML classes they contain to edit them.

It looks like https://www.drupal.org/project/block_search isn't up to date anymore - is there a convenient way to search the admin section of a drupal site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the block you're looking for is a "custom block", i.e. one that you create via structure->blocks->Add block rather than one defined in a module then you should be able to query the database for it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM block_custom WHERE body like '%my-class%'
```

...changing "my-class" as appropriate.

Alternatively, you can inspect the markup of the block on the front end and look for a class such as block-123, then navigate to /admin/structure/block/manage/block/123/configure, replacing 123 with whichever block number you found.

If there's no body field on that page then it's probably a block defined by a module.  Then you can try to find a clue as to where it's defined in the classes on the contents of the block, for example if you see lots of classes with the word views in it then it will be a block defined in views and you should look in the views UI to find where it's defined.

Also, turning on the core contextual links module may help as well.

n.b. All this is based on the assumption that we're talking about Drupal 7.  Much of it applies for other versions with some tweaking.

Comment: @Paul_Querol thank you! Question - is there a similar way to search content of views or blocks defined by modules?

Comment: Not really unfortunately, depending on the module that's defining the block it could be in a table specific to the module or in code or even pulled in from a third party website (unlikely).  You could grep the code base and if that doesn't turn anything up dump the database as an SQL file and grep that.